# Maximizing after moving RDC window between different size monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

My Win7 system has two monitors of different sizes. When I open a Remote Desktop Connection on one monitor set to use full screen, both the RDC window and the remote system's desktop fills the monitor. If I then move the window onto my second monitor (1-Restore Down button to make it movable; 2-Drag window to other monitor; 3-Maximize button to fill monitor) the RDC window fills the monitor, but the remote system's desktop remains the same size it was before.

Thus, if I move from the larger to the smaller monitor I have scrollbars to see the whole remote desktop, while if I move from the smaller to the larger monitor the remote desktop occupies only a portion of the monitor. My workaround is to close the RDC window completely then re-establish it on the other monitor. Is there a way to avoid this overhead and just resize the remote desktop to fit?

Comment: I also observed this type of problem in my Window 7 OS. But my friend has Window 10 OS and he is able to drag remote desktop from one screen to another and achieving full remote desktop screen on both displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your workaround is the only method supported by RDP.

The screen resolution is set when the session is established in the Display settings.  Even when you select "Full Screen" in the display settings, all that is happening is the resolution of the current screen is passed through to the session when it commences.

So it won't then take on the "full screen" resolution of the second screen by moving it there, you need to restart the session to send through the new "full screen" resolution.